# How to download a CSV file in website in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, csv, yahoo-finance

In my website I am trying to download a CSV which comes from Yahoo. It contains some data.

I am using the code given below to download CSV.

**Problem:**

I want to download and fetch all the data from Yahoo's CSV but the whole CSV is not getting created on my side.

Only some portion of the data is copied. So CSV is not downloaded with all its data.

**I tried increasing the Buffer size but that didn't help**

**Data in Yahoo's CSV is as shown in below screenshot. This is the data I want to download**

[image]

**Data that I get in created CSV, when I download the same Yahoo's CSV is as shown below.**

[image]

**Code I am using to download the CSV from Yahoo**

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=^DJI+^N225+^GSPC+^GDAXI+^FCHI+^HSI+^IXIC+^FTSE&f=l1d14n");
        HttpWebResponse ws = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
        Stream str = ws.GetResponseStream();
        inBuf = new Byte[10000000];
        int bytesToRead = Convert.ToInt32(inBuf.ToString().Length);

        int bytesRead=0;
        while(bytesToRead>0)
        {
            int n = str.Read(inBuf,bytesRead,bytesToRead);
            if(n==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            bytesRead += n;
            bytesToRead -= n;
        }
        FileStream fstr = new FileStream("C:\\VSS Working Folder\\20th Jan 11 NewHive\\NewHive\\CSV\\new.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        fstr.Write(inBuf,0,bytesRead);
        str.Close();
        fstr.Close();
        return "CSV Downloaded Successfully!";
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: What do you see if you open the CSV in a text editor rather than a spreadsheet?

Comment: @Kirk: If I open it in notepad, I see something like this `10274.52,"1/2` . What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inBuf.ToString()` gives you "System.Byte[]" and the length of that string is 13.  So you are only saving 13 characters which will only give you  `10274.52,"1/2` from the downloaded file.

You can get the length using `inBuf.Length`.  Note that Length returns an int so you don't need to cast to an int.

Comment: Ok so how can I take the length of the whole buffer?

Comment: Thanks I got it working. Just needed to replace `inBuf.ToString().Length`   to   `(int) inBuf.Length;` . Thanks a lot. It was a silly mistake on my part. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.